# Not implementing interface member in service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

First of all I apologize if the references to this question are not correct.

I am developing a three-tier `MVC 3` application. In the business layer I need to create a service which will call the Data Access Layer, in order to retrieve a list of existing towns.

My `ITown` interface is as follows;

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITown
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Town> GetAllTowns();
}
```

In the `Town.svc.cs`, I am inserting as follows;

```
public class Town : ITown
{
    public IEnumerable<Common.Town> GetAllTowns()
    {
        return new DATown().GetAllTowns();
    }
}
```

The problem is in the above code.  I am getting an error under `Town` in the class declaration `public class Town : ITown`.

```
'Business.Town' does not implement interface member 'Business.ITown.GetAllTowns()'. 
'Business.Town.GetAllTowns()' cannot implement 'Business.ITown.GetAllTowns()'
because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Business.Town>'.
```

This is the content in my `DATown`;

```
public class DATown : Connection
{
    //Constructor
    public DATown()
        :base()
    { }

    public IEnumerable<Town> GetAllTowns()
    {
        return entities.Town.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

So basically what I am doing is calling the `GetAllTowns()` method of `DATown` from the `Town.svc.cs` class.

I've searched around for other similar queries; mostly saying that there is a correct parameter in one of the methods. I do not think that this is the case with my code.

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Town class you have an `IEnumerable<Common.Town>` and in the interface you've simply got `IEnumerable<Town>`, but in your error it shows that the interface is using `Business.Town` and not  `Common.Town`. The issue is that these are not the same as each other.

If you change your Interface so the IEnumerable is also of Common.Town you should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

From what I see, you've got an incorrect return type - your Town in ITown is Bussiness.Town, whereas in the service class you return  Common.Town. Try returning Bussiness.Town in svc